# Unable to save Kik channel configuration- Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, kik

I am unable to save Kik configuration in my bot service. I've opened an issue here as well- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/issues/81. So, I just want to ask if its a bug or not? [image: ScreenShot of the error]

Comment: Are you using the kik bot's display name, or your own personal display name?

Answer (score 0):

The Display Name placeholder text currently states: "Your Kik display name"  This should be the Kik bot's display name, from the Configuration tab on https://dev.kik.com

[image]

Comment: Okay. I have resolved this by putting bot's name instead of Bot's display name. That needs to be corrected.